# All sets length 2 from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, combinatorics

This seems like a canned numpy or scipy function...but I can't find it.

I have an array of tuples, where the tuples contain mean and standard deviations of classes.  I need a second array with all the unique combinations of the tuples with eachother (so all of the subsets of length 2 from the array).

so, for example:

```
original = [(0.5,0.112),(2.3,0.1),(5,0.7)]
```

And I need:

```
subsets = [((0.5,0.112),(2.3,0.1)),/
           ((0.5,0.112),(5,0.7)),/
           ((2.3,0.1),(5,0.7))]
```

for an arbitrarily lengthed original array.

What I've got right now:

```
def subsets_length_2(vector):
    subset_vector = []
    for i in vector:
        for j in vector:
            if i != j:
                subset_vector.append((i,j))
    subset_vector = np.asarray(np.unique(subset_vector))
    return subset_vector
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use itertools.combinations:

```
import itertools
subsets = list(itertools.combinations(original, 2))
print subsets
# [((0.5, 0.112), (2.3, 0.1)), ((0.5, 0.112), (5, 0.7)), ((2.3, 0.1), (5, 0.7))]
```

Comment: This looks like what I was thinking.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can still use a double for loop, but it's not necessary to loop over the entire array with the inner for loop.

```
def subsets_length_2(vector):
    subset_vector = []
    n = len(vector)
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            subset_vector.append((vector[i],vector[j])) 
    return np.asarray(subset_vector)
```